# How to clear the cache of openarena game?

Tags: configuration, openarena

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed Open Arena game and made some configuration mistake that removes mouse click for shooting. I can't revert the configuration. Even when I uninstall and reinstall the game the configuration remains the same. I know the problem was with the cache. How can I clear the game cache?

Comment: "uninstall" what was the command used? If not "sudo apt purge" ... purge removes configurations files ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind not the config in a user's home directory.

Comment: Chech in the `/etc/` folder with `ls /etc | grep arena`

Comment: Thank you @Rinzwind .The problem is with the .openarena header file in my home directory, once I delete that header file all my configurations rollback to the default setup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with (.openarena) header file in the home directory, once you delete that header file all the configurations rollback to the default setup.